# Microsoft.XMLHTTP not working for URLs that have been shortened

Tags: javascript

Here's my working example for testing a URL to see if it exists or not.

Trouble is it doesn't work for any URLs' that have been shortened with URL shorteners.

See the code below and let me know where it could be improved to fix this issue.

```
String.prototype.XMLHTTPValidURL = function() {
  urlTest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  var url = this.replace(/^ +| +$/g, ''); // Trims the url before testing.
  try { urlTest.open('GET', url, false);
  urlTest.send();
  if (urlTest.status != 404) return url;
} catch(err) {return false} }

// Due to stackoverflow not allowing shortened URLs, I had to wrap an encoded URL below
console.log(decodeURIComponent('http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F1sNZMwL').XMLHTTPValidURL()); // This doesn't work.
console.log('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'.XMLHTTPValidURL()); // This works.
```

Comment: What's an example of shortened url

Comment: Any, I cannot post shortened URLs here.

Comment: Yes you cannot do XHR cross origin in old Microsoft.XMLHTTP api.  If you're on the same origin then it's possible.

Comment: Has nothing to do with being shortened.  I imagine 
 querying http://www.supercalifragilisticexpialidocious.com/ would give you the same unwanted result.

Comment: No, that returns true, meaning it will return the URL in the above function. Shortened URLs don't work.

Comment: And these shortened urls contain the protocol and definitely resolve to 200 OK?  Do you mind if I place a resolvable example shortened url in your snippet?  Or, I believe you can place the shortened URL here and I should be able to replace it in the question.

Comment: It returns 0. I cannot even post them to the comments at all. But I'm using https://bitly.com/ to shorten them.

Comment: Example updated

Comment: `new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');` please use the modern XMLHttpRequest instead of ancient activeX unless you are really developing with IE8.

Comment: Weird it would work because of the same origin policy preventing cross domain calls.

Comment: There is nothing special about shortened URLs, they are still URLs. A shortened URL is simply a redirect to another URL. The `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` request just doesn't want to follow the redirect across domains. (e.g. from `bit.ly` to `en.wikipedia.org` in your example).

Comment: @epascarello, yes, that's the case, unfortunately. _Jake Holzinger_, ok, that makes sense.